# Postgresql does not launch

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I just installed postgresql 9.1 on my ubuntu server precise
I installed postgres on an ubuntu workstation before and despite following the same steps (documented) nothing works.

When i do :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

There is no message at all, and there is no postgres process running. The /var/log/postgres/ folder exist but it's empty. How can i know what is wrong with my postgres?

EDIT : nothing relevant in var/log/messages

Comment: Is there anything in your other server logs, e.g. `/var/log/messages` that will give you a hint?

Comment: What's the output of `pg_lsclusters`? If it's empty, that would explain why the init script starts nothing without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally deleted and reinstalled postgres, half of postgres was missing. I only used apt-get i'm not sure why the installation failed. After a clean install it waorks perfectly.